# Web Scraping with Python: problem with BeautifulSoup

Tags: beautifulsoup

Please help me with the use of BeautifulSoup to web scraping finaces values from investing.com using Python 3.
Whatever I do never get any value, and the filting class is changing permanently from the web page at it is a live value.

```
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://es.investing.com/indices/spain-35-futures"
precio_objetivo = input("Introduce el PRECIO del disparador:")
precio_objetivo = float(precio_objetivo)
print (precio_objetivo)

while True:
html = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
precio_actual = soup.find('span', attrs={'class': 'arial_26 inlineblock pid-8828-last','id':'last_last','dir':'ltr'})
print (precio_actual)
break;
```

When I don't apply any filter at soup.find (trying at least to get all the web page) I get this result:

```
<bound method Tag.find_all of 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
```

"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

```
<html>
<head>
<title>403 You are banned from this site.  Please contact via a different client configuration if you believe that this is a mistake.                                </title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Error 403 You are banned from this site.  Please contact via a different client configuration if you believe that this is a mistake.</h1>
<p>You are banned from this site.  Please contact via a different client configuration if you believe that this is a mistake.</p>
<h3>Guru Meditation:</h3>
<p>XID: 850285196</p>
<hr/>
<p>Varnish cache server</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like that website detects where the request is coming from, so we need to 'fool' it into thinking we're on a browser.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

r = Request("https://es.investing.com/indices/spain-35-futures", headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0"})
c = urlopen(r).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(c, "html.parser")
print(soup)
```

Answer (score 1):

The web server detects the python script as a bot and hence blocks it.
By using headers you can prevent it and the following code does it:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://es.investing.com/indices/spain-35-futures"

header={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2227.0 Safari/537.36'}
page=requests.get(url,headers=header)

soup=BeautifulSoup(page.content,'html.parser')
#this soup returns <span class="arial_26 inlineblock pid-8828-last" dir="ltr" id="last_last">9.182,5</span>

result = soup.find('span',attrs={'id':'last_last'}).get_text()
#use the get_text() function to extract the text

print(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using selenium web driver. As otherwise you will face this thing more if the number of requests are high. Also sometimes there are problem with sites having JavaScript.

```
from selenium import webdriver
url = 'https://example.com/'
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options,executable_path='/usr/local/bin/chromedriver')
driver.get(url)
```