# Scraping data from investing.com using python

Tags: python

I have been trying to scrape data from yahoo finance but every time I try I get the following errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\nnarn\PycharmProjects\papaproject\main.py", line 14, in <module>
    print(str(parsePrice()))
  File "C:\Users\nnarn\PycharmProjects\papaproject\main.py", line 10, in parsePrice
    price = soup.find('div', {'class': 'last u-up'}).find('bdo').text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'
```

The code I wrote is:-

```py
 import bs4
 import requests
 
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
 
 
 def parsePrice():
    r = requests.get('https://in.investing.com/indices/usdollar')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    price = soup.find('div', {'class': 'last u-up'}).find('bdo').text
    return price
 
 while True:
    print(str(parsePrice()))
```

Comment: Your answer can be found [in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56506210/web-scraping-with-python-problem-with-beautifulsoup).

Comment: Thank you, that kind of helped but now I am getting a different issue because from this stock the attributes are different and so when I try doing almost the same thing I get none as a constantly repeating error (https://in.investing.com/indices/usdollar)

Comment: can you show your updated code?